# QuickBlox Unauthorized using CURL PHP

Tags: quickblox

Have been using a PHP script to read custom objects for weeks. Today I started to get {"errors":["Unauthorized"]} replies. I can still log-on using the web-portal and the same credentials. Android app still works well using the same QuickBlox App. Have been scratching my head.. Can someone please help?

Code:

```
<?php

 // Application credentials - change to yours (found in QB Dashboard)
 DEFINE('APPLICATION_ID', 99999);
 DEFINE('AUTH_KEY', "AbCd...");
 DEFINE('AUTH_SECRET', "ZxYvW...");

 // User credentials
 DEFINE('USER_LOGIN', "user@domain.com");
 DEFINE('USER_PASSWORD', "password");

 // Quickblox endpoints
 DEFINE('QB_API_ENDPOINT', "https://api.quickblox.com");
 DEFINE('QB_PATH_SESSION', "session.json");

 // Generate signature
 $nonce = rand();
 $timestamp = time(); // time() method must return current timestamp in UTC but seems like hi is return timestamp in current time zone
 $signature_string = "application_id=".APPLICATION_ID."&auth_key=".AUTH_KEY."&nonce=".$nonce."&timestamp=".$timestamp."&user[login]=".USER_LOGIN."&user[password]=".USER_PASSWORD;

 echo "stringForSignature: " . $signature_string . "<br><br>";
 $signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $signature_string , AUTH_SECRET);

 // Build post body
 $post_body = http_build_query(array(
                 'application_id' => APPLICATION_ID,
                 'auth_key' => AUTH_KEY,
                 'timestamp' => $timestamp,
                 'nonce' => $nonce,
                 'signature' => $signature,
                 'user[login]' => USER_LOGIN,
                 'user[password]' => USER_PASSWORD
                 ));

 echo "postBody: " . $post_body . "<br><br>";
 // Configure cURL
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, QB_API_ENDPOINT . '/' . QB_PATH_SESSION); // Full path is - https://api.quickblox.com/session.json
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); // Use POST
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_body); // Setup post body
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Receive server response

 // Execute request and read response
 $response = curl_exec($curl);

 // Check errors
 if ($response) {
         echo $response . "\n";
 } else {
         $error = curl_error($curl). '(' .curl_errno($curl). ')';
         echo $error . "\n";
 }

 $jsonResponse = json_decode($response,true);
 $qbToken = $jsonResponse['session']['token'];
```

Comment: Same here. You solve?

Answer (score 0):

1.First you need to check the credential for quickblox which you pass in the script like appId,authKey

2.Then need to check that user registered in the same quickblox account or not .

3.One more thing you need to know that in php the password of quick account should be more then 8 char.